# Java: How to assign or read JSON data returned from a postgresql Query into JPA Repository method. [query: SELECT row_to_json(...)]

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, geojson

I have the below code situated in the JpaRepository on a spring boot project, the query returns a JSON structured as GeoJson as below.

I am getting the Error: **Resolved [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111]***

```
  String queryString = "SELECT row_to_json(fc)\n" +
          " FROM ( SELECT 'FeatureCollection' As type, array_to_json(array_agg(f)) As features\n" +
          " FROM (SELECT 'Feature' As type\n" +
          "    , ST_AsGeoJSON(lg.column1) As geometry\n" +
          "    , row_to_json((column2, column3)) As properties\n" +
          "   FROM public.table As lg ) As f )  As fc;";


  @Query(value=queryString, nativeQuery=true) 
  Json getData(@Param("id") Long id);
```

In application.properties file i set my Dialect to/as:

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect
```

The Query returns a GeoJson FeatureCollection Object, and i want to assign or be able to read it into java.

Please bare with me with the way i asked the question, i am new here.

returned GeoJson would look something like this:

```
{"type" : "FeatureCollection", "features" : [{"type": "Feature", "geometry": {"type":"Point","coordinates":[1,1]}, "properties": {"id": 1, "name": "one"}}, {"type": "Feature", "geometry": {"type":"Point","coordinates":[2,2]}, "properties": {"id": 2, "name": "two"}}, {"type": "Feature", "geometry": {"type":"Point","coordinates":[3,3]}, "properties": {"id": 3, "name": "three"}}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are trying to achieve here exactly, but guess you need to use `String` as return type and parse that JSON string in another method.

Comment: I am building a GeoJson object from that query. I tried assigning it to a string but it doesnt work. The query would return something like this: 


` {"type" : "FeatureCollection", "features" : [{"type": "Feature", "geometry": {"type":"Point","coordinates":[1,1]}, "properties": {"id": 1, "name": "one"}}, {"type": "Feature", "geometry": {"type":"Point","coordinates":[2,2]}, "properties": {"id": 2, "name": "two"}}, {"type": "Feature", "geometry": {"type":"Point","coordinates":[3,3]}, "properties": {"id": 3, "name": "three"}}]} `

Its a complex json object cant create a dto/projection for it

Comment: Apart from the fact, that what I suggested should work(you need to debug or check in with spring-data people if not) I can only suggest you to fetch objects instead and do the JSON serialization in Java code.